# Jquery: Dynamically changing the <class> of a <link> depending on the pathname

Tags: jquery, window.location

We want to add class on a **link** depending on **window.location.pathname**

our html is:

```
  <nav>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a href="company.php">Company</a>
    <a href="products.php">Products</a>
    <a href="technical.php">Technical</a>
    <a href="services.php">Services</a>
    <a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
```

and the document URL is *www.nicadpower.com/index.php* and so we did

```
var page_name = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
```

after getting/knowing the pathname to be **'index.php'** we want jquery to do it's tricks comparing the **'page_name'** to **href** and if it's equal would add a **class="current"**

making our html code to be like this

```
  <nav>
    <a href="index.php" class="current">Home</a>
    <a href="company.php">Company</a>
    <a href="products.php">Products</a>
    <a href="technical.php">Technical</a>
    <a href="services.php">Services</a>
    <a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("a[href='" + page_name + "']").addClass("current");
```

That will select the `a` element with the required `href` attribute value, and add a class to it. See example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/P9Xvd/).

Answer (score 4):

You may not need JavaScript for this at all, see the example at the end.

You're looking for the ["attribute equals selector"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), <s>or possibly the ["attribute ends with"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector</s> *nope, the equals selector works*:

```
// The equals selector
$('nav a[href="' + page_name + '"]').addClass('current');

// The ends-with selector
$('nav a[href$="' + page_name + '"]').addClass('current');
```

The "attribute equals selector" is [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) and broadly-supported, so you could probably do this without JavaScript at all, just using a stylesheet. The ends-with selector is [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) and probably not as well supported, certainly not if you need to support older browsers.

[Here's an example page](http://jsbin.com/iseme4/2) using both jQuery and CSS. The CSS version using the "attribute equals" selector works fine on IE7 and up, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari. (The CSS bit doesn't work on IE6, quelle shock.)

Comment: Better solution over all. No need for any scripting, all done neatly via CSS. Not sure why this didn't get accepted.